On the equivalence in measurability of two different definitions of a playing strategy for a multi-armed bandit
Consider a $d$-armed bandit.
At each time $t\in\mathbb{N}^+$ one of the arms is pulled
and some reward is gained.
For each arm $i=1,\ldots,d$
let $\pi_{i,t}$ be the number of times that arm $i$ has been pulled
at time $t$.
The random variables $\pi_{i,t}$
describe a strategy for playing the arms:

At time $t=0$ no arms have been played yet
and $\pi_{1,0} = \ldots = \pi_{d,0} = 0$.

At any time $t\in\mathbb{N}^+$,
if arm $i$ is being pulled
then its number of pulls increases by one, i.e.,
$\pi_{i,t} = \pi_{i,t-1} + 1$,
and for the other arms the number of pulls remains the same, i.e.,
$\pi_{j,t} = \pi_{j,t-1}$ for $j\neq i$.


This is the approach that I read in an article by Mandelbaum (1986).
My question:
Instead of using the $\pi_{i,t}$ as a definition of a playing strategy,
I would like to define it as a $\{1,\ldots,d\}$-valued stochastic process
$(\pi_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}^+}$
where $\pi_t$ is the arm played at time $t$.
I believe these two definitions should be equivalent,
but I am not sure how to show this as far as measurability is concerned.
In his article,
Mandelbaum models the information accumulated through $u$ pulls of arm $i$
by a $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}_{i,u}$,
yielding a filtration
$(\mathscr{F}_{i,u})_{u\in\mathbb{N}}$
for each arm $i$.
These filtrations for different arms are assumed to be independent.
He then requires that each random variable $\pi_{i,t}$
is a stopping time of the filtration
$(\mathscr{F}_{i,u})_{u\in\mathbb{N}}$,
i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\{\pi_{i,t} = u\}\in\mathscr{F}_{i,u}
\text{ for each }u\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation*}
From this I believe I can derive measurability conditions for $\pi_t$,
and from the latter I believe I should be able to recover
that the $\pi_{i,t}$ are stopping times of
$(\mathscr{F}_{i,u})_{u\in\mathbb{N}}$,
but that is not what I find.
My approach so far:
I adopt Mandelbaum's approach
that the $\pi_{i,t}$ are stopping times of
$(\mathscr{F}_{i,u})_{u\in\mathbb{N}}$.
Suppose that at time $t\in\mathbb{N}^+$ I pull arm $i$,
i.e., $\pi_t = i$.
That means that at time $t$ I have pulled arm $i$
at least once and at most $t$ times,
so I can write the event $\{\pi_t = i\}$
in terms of random variables $\pi_{i,t}$ by the identity
\begin{equation*}
\{\pi_t = i\} 
= 
\{\pi_{i,t} 
= 
\pi_{i,t-1}+1\} 
= 
\bigcup^t_{u=1}\{\pi_{i,t}=u\}\cap\{\pi_{i,t-1}=u-1\}.
\end{equation*}
Since by assumption
$\{\pi_{i,t} = u\}\in\mathscr{F}_{i,u}$ for each $u\in\mathbb{N}$
it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\{\pi_t = i\}\in\mathscr{F}_{i,t}.
\end{equation*}
Conversely,
if at time $t$ the number of times that I have pulled arm $i$
equals $u\in\mathbb{N}$,
i.e., $\pi_{i,t} = u$,
then the event $\{\pi_{i,t} = u\}$ equals the union of all possible combinations
of $u$ pulls of arm $i$ at times $1,\ldots,t$,
i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\{\pi_{i,t} = u\}
=
\bigcup_{S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,t\},|S|=u}
\bigg(\bigcap_{s\in S}\{\pi_s = i\}\bigg)
\cap
\bigg(\bigcap_{s\in\{1,\ldots,t\}\setminus S}\{\pi_s\neq i\}\bigg).
\end{equation*}
But since I found that
$\{\pi_s = i\}\in\mathscr{F}_{i,s}$ for each $s$,
I find that
\begin{equation*}
\{\pi_{i,t} = u\}\in\mathscr{F}_{i,t}
\text{ for each }u\in\mathbb{N},
\end{equation*}
which seems to contradict the starting assumption that
each $\pi_{i,t}$ is a stopping time of the filtration
$(\mathscr{F}_{i,u})_{u\in\mathbb{N}}$.
Did I make a mistake somewhere?
Is my thought wrong
that I can write events $\{\pi_t = i\}$ in terms of events $\{\pi_{i,t}=u\}$
and vice versa,
including to which $\sigma$-fields they belong?

So I have come to the following answer
for the specific case of
a Markovian multi-armed bandit consisting of independent machines $1,\ldots,d$,
where we have total knowledge of the states of the machines.
The two approaches appear to be equivalent.
Let each machine $i$ be described by
a state process $(X_{i,t})_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$
and a reward function $r_i$.
The states $X_{i,t}$ of machine $i$
are random variables into a measurable space $(\mathbb{S}_i,\mathfrak{S}_i)$,
and the reward function $r_i$
is a measurable function $\mathbb{S}_i\to\mathbb{R}$.
The machines considered together
as a process
in $\mathbb{S}_1\times\cdots\times\mathbb{S}_d$
induces a natural filtration
$(\mathfrak{N}_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$
defined for each $t$ by
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak{N}_t
=
\sigma(\{(X_{1,s},\ldots,X_{d,s})\in S_1\times\cdots\times S_d\}:
s\in\mathbb{N}, s\leq t,
S_1\in\mathfrak{S}_1,\ldots,S_d\in\mathfrak{S}_d)
.
\end{equation*}
At each time $t\in\mathbb{N}$
we assume to have total knowledge of the states of the machines up to time $t$,
which means that the joint process
$X_t = (X_{1,t},\ldots,X_{d,t})$, $t\in\mathbb{N}$,
is $(\mathfrak{N}_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$-adapted.
At each time $t\in\mathbb{N}^+$
one of the machines $i = 1,\ldots,d$ is played,
putting it in a state $X_{i,t}$
typically different from its previous one $X_{i,t-1}$,
the other machines $j\neq i$ remain frozen,
i.e., $X_{j,t-1} = X_{j,t}$,
and a reward $r_i(X_{i,t})$ is obtained.
The act of choosing a machine to play at every time $t\in\mathbb{N}^+$
can be described by a process
\begin{equation*}
\pi:\mathbb{N}^+\times\Omega
\ni(t,\omega)\mapsto\pi_t(\omega)\in
\{1,\ldots,d\}
,
\end{equation*}
which we will call an allocation policy.
We require an allocation policy $\pi$
to be adapted to the natural filtration
$(\mathfrak{N}_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$,
so that the choice of the machine played
at each time is based on the information available up to that time:
for each $t\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and each $i=1,\ldots,d$
we have
\begin{equation*}
\{\pi_t = i\}\in\mathfrak{N}_t.
\end{equation*}
This way of modelling a multi-armed bandit
is common for a stochastic control problem,
of which the Markovian multi-armed bandit is a subclass,
and it is the one adopted by Karatzas (1984).
A seemingly different description is where
the knowledge about each individual machine $i$
is modelled by a separate filtration,
where the filtration is indexed not by time
but by the number of times it has been played.
This is the approach adopted by
Varaiya, Walrand & Buyukkoc (1985)
and
Mandelbaum (1986).
Each machine $i$ individually induces a natural filtration
$(\mathfrak{N}_{i,t})_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$
defined for each $t$ by
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak{N}_{i,t}
=
\sigma(\{X_{i,s}\in S\}:s\in\mathbb{N}, s\leq t, S\in\mathfrak{S}_i)
.
\end{equation*}
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
if machine $i$ at a time $t$ has been played $n$ times
then let $\tilde{\mathfrak{N}}_{i,n}$ be the $\sigma$-field $\mathfrak{N}_{i,t}$.
At each time $t\in\mathbb{N}$
there will be $n_1,\ldots,n_d\in\mathbb{N}$
such that machine $i$ will have been played $n_i$ times at time $t$,
and since
$\mathfrak{N}_t = \bigvee^d_{i=1}\mathfrak{N}_{i,t}$,
we find that
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak{N}_t = \bigvee^d_{i=1}\tilde{\mathfrak{N}}_{i,n_i},
\end{equation*}
so the $\sigma$-fields
$\tilde{\mathfrak{N}}_{1,n_1},\ldots,\tilde{\mathfrak{N}}_{d,n_d}$
contain the same information as $\mathfrak{N}_t$.
Let $\pi$ be an allocation policy
and for $i = 1,\ldots,d$ and each $t\in\mathbb{N}$
let $\pi_{i,t}$ be
the number of times that machine $i$ has been played at time $t$,
i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\pi_{i,t}
=
|\{1\leq s\leq t:\pi_s = i\}|
.
\end{equation*}
It is immediate from the definitions that
$\pi_{i,t}$
for each $t\in\mathbb{N}$
is a Markov time of the filtration
$(\tilde{\mathfrak{N}}_{i,n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$,
i.e.,
that for each $i = 1,\ldots,d$ and $t,n\in\mathbb{N}$
the event $\{\pi_{i,t} = n\}$
that machine $i$ has been played $n$ times at time $t$
lies in $\tilde{\mathfrak{N}}_{i,n}$.
Another way of seeing this
is that the event $\{\pi_{i,t} = n\}$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\{\pi_{i,t} = n\}
=
\bigcup_{S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,t\},|S| = n}
\bigg(\bigcap_{s\in S}\{\pi_s = i\}\bigg)
\cap
\bigg(\bigcap_{s\in\{1,\ldots,t\}\setminus S}\{\pi_s\neq i\}\bigg)
,
\end{equation*}
where the sets $S$ are the moments in time that machine $i$ is played,
and the union is one of events that all lie in $\tilde{\mathfrak{N}}_{i,n}$.
